# Liberty 18.0.0.2: jaxrs-2.0 is not working with ldapRegistry-3.0

Tags: jax-rs, classnotfoundexception, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm trying to upgrade my applications from Liberty 18.0.0.1 to 18.0.0.2 but they all are now failing on:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter
 ...
```

[stacktrace](https://ibm.box.com/s/n6ifdcpb97lzqwuby7xr7tt67kwv11oq)

the problem seems to be with ldapRegistry-3.0 - once that feature is enabled all jax-rs requests are failing. Once I remove ldapRegistry the code works fine, but I need this feature for my applications...

I've even built small example to demonstrate it, with single RestEndpoint /v1/api/employee : [Sample project](https://ibm.box.com/s/i660dqmqbasfb1xtdxn62jaydshddh1t) [server config](https://ibm.box.com/s/ud9w748tpipcktz9z0ppzzx8rwp9hma3)

Is this a bug, can I report it somewhere? or am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the [server dump](https://ibm.box.com/s/maw4iybbywtbpmp0y2s8rul1nhtv9qm2)

Thank you

Comment: you can report this bug on the OpenLiberty github repo: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty

Comment: I believe someone else reported the same issue you are observing, which I am working on fixing here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/4404

Comment: Oh, cool. I'll add a comment to that bug.
Thank you @AndyGuibert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a subtle split package classloading conflict.  I was able to reproduce this issue with Liberty 18.0.0.2 and the underlying exception looks something like this:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler.createUnmarshaller(javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler)

In this case it seems that `javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler` was loaded from classloader A, and `javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler` was loaded twice -- once from classloader A and once from classloader B.  The error we get here is caused by the JVM looking for `javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler.createUnmarshaller(javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler)` where both classes are from classloader A, but instead it looks for a `createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler)` method where `ValidationEventHandler` comes from classloader B.

This bug will be resolved in the next version of Liberty (18.0.0.3)